# Gorilla/sessions cookie not being set when SessionStore is from exported package

Tags: go, gorilla

I'm having an issue with [gorilla/sessions](https://github.com/gorilla/sessions). My sessions aren't being saved when `sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("veryprivatekey"))` is from a different package/exported variable.

Here is what works:

### What works

exampleproj/main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
    "net/http"
)

var store *sessions.CookieStore
var cookie_name = "sess"


func main() {
    store = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("veryprivatekey"))
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/cookietest", cookietest)
    router.HandleFunc("/cookietest2", cookietest2)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
}

var cookietest = func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, err := store.Get(r, cookie_name)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    session.Values["Stack"] = "Overflow"
    err = session.Save(r,w)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

var cookietest2 = func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, err := store.Get(r, cookie_name)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Stack: ", session.Values["Stack"])
}
```

(open localhost:8080/cookietest and check that a cookie was created)

### The issue

Here is some code where `sessions.CookieStore` is from another package:

exampleproj/main.go

```
package main

import (
    "expirements/example"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "net/http"
)

var cookie_name = "sess"


func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/cookietest", cookietest)
    router.HandleFunc("/cookietest2", cookietest2)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
}

var cookietest = func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, err := example.Store.Get(r, cookie_name)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    session.Values["Stack"] = "Overflow"
    err = session.Save(r,w)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

var cookietest2 = func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, err := example.Store.Get(r, cookie_name)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Stack: ", session.Values["Stack"])
}
```

exampleproj/example/ex.go

```
package example

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
)

var Store *sessions.CookieStore

func init() {
    Store = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("veryprivatekey"))
    Store.Options = &sessions.Options{
        //Domain:   config.Host,
        //Path:     "/",
        MaxAge:   259200,
        Secure:   true,
        HttpOnly: true,
    }
}

func GetStore() *sessions.CookieStore {
    return Store
}
```

No cookies were set. I've also tried using `GetStore()` instead of `example.Store`, but that didn't work either. Am I supposed to declare a `sessions.NewCookieStore` for each package?

Comment: Why are you changing `Store.Options` in the second example but not in the first? What if you don’t change them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028304/how-to-use-gorilla-sessions-in-golang-in-different-packages) - surprised I couldn't find more stackoverflow questions about this.